# Speeding up levenshtein / similar_text in PHP

Tags: php, levenshtein-distance, similarity

I am currently using [similar_text](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) to compare a string against a list of ~50,000 which works although due to the number of comparisons it's very slow. It takes around 11 minutes to compare ~500 unique strings.

Before running this I do check the databases to see whether it has been processed in the past so everytime after the inital run it's close to instant.

I'm sure using [levenshtein](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) would be slightly faster and the LevenshteinDistance function someone posted in the manual looks interesting. Am I missing something that could make this significantly faster?

Comment: `O(N**3)` where N is the length of the longest string for `similar_text`... ouch.

Comment: What is the average length of the strings? Aaandd... how much of the data in the string is actually relevant to the search? i.e. How much is just cruft?

Comment: The average length is around 20 characters and a high percentage of the data is relevant, perhaps 85-95%. I think perhaps using these are a little overkill and I could probably just use a full text search in mysql followed by a few checks.

Comment: If only close matches is needed, some quick checks using string length can be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end, both `levenshtein` and `similar_text` were both too slow with the number of strings it had to go through, even with lots of checks and only using them one of them as a last resort.

As an experiment, I ported some of the code to C# to see how much faster it would be over interperated code. It ran in about 3 minutes with the same dataset.

Next I added an extra field to the table and used the double metaphone PECL extension to generate keys for each row. The results were good although since some included numbers this caused duplicates. I guess I could then have run each one through the above functions but decided not to.

In the end I opted for the simplest approach, MySQLs full text which worked very well. Occasionally there are mistakes although they are easy to detect and correct. Also it runs very fast, in around 3-4 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could 'short-circuit' some checks by first comparing your string for an exact match (and by first comparing if length identical), and if it is skip the more expensive `similar_text` call.

As @jason noted, an O(N^3) algorithm is never going to be a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

When using levenshtein automaton (automaton that matches a string with distance `k`) you can do a check for matching in `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of the string you are checking. Constructing the automaton will take `O(kn)`, where `k` is max distance and `n` length of the base string.